# Using multiplot but only using one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

May question is a bit strange. I'll explain you my situation, Maybe someone knows another workaround. Assume I've 5 plots (just for convenience assume that plot 3 and 5 are identical)

```
library(ggplot2)

# This example uses the ChickWeight dataset, which comes with ggplot2
# First plot
p1 <- ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Diet, group=Chick)) +
  geom_line() 

# Second plot
p2 <- ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Diet)) +
  geom_point(alpha=.3) +
  geom_smooth(alpha=.2, size=1) 


# Third plot
p3 <- ggplot(subset(ChickWeight, Time==21), aes(x=weight, colour=Diet)) +
  geom_density()

# Fourth plot
p4 <- ggplot(subset(ChickWeight, Time==21), aes(x=weight, fill=Diet)) +
  geom_histogram(colour="black", binwidth=50) +
  facet_grid(Diet ~ .) +
  theme(legend.position="none")   # No legend (redundant in this graph)   

p5 <- p3

multiplot(p1, p2, p3, p4, cols=2)
```

I am using the multiplot function to create one picture with 4 subplot. I want know create 2nd "multiplot" with 2 columns but only on graph. However I didnt find a solution to handle it.
The backround is that the 4 plots are taking one Din-A4 side. And I dont want to reduce their size to create a multiplot with 5 subplots. Therefore I want to seperate the 4 plots and the one into two figures, but the 5th plot should have the same size as the 4 subplot. Therefore my idea was to create another multiplot with 2 cols but one empty plot. I hope you get my problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't strongly rely on `coefplot::multiplot()` you could use `egg::ggarrange()` with defined widths. For best results concerning the widths  export the plots with e.g. `png()`. However, the height of the single plot is a bit tricky. To get it right you could add a completely empty plot.

```
p.empty <- ggplot() + theme_void()

png("plot1.png", width = 480, height = 480)
egg::ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2, widths=c(3, 3))
dev.off()

png("plot2.png", width = 480, height = 480)
egg::ggarrange(p5, p.empty, p.empty, ncol=2, nrow=2, widths=c(3, 5))
dev.off()
```

*Note:* Second part of argument `widths=c(3, 5)` is bigger because of the missing legend in the empty plot.

***Result***

*First plot*

[image]

*Second plot*

[image]